# AWS Cloudformation Cloudwatch Dashboard : Ref ApiGateway Title

Tags: yaml, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Cloudformation template which has API Gateway defined with title `Employee Management API`. I like to reference this title when I define a Cloudwatch Dashboard for the API Gateway. Right now I hard coded the title of the API Gateway into the dashboard metrics. Instead if I am able to Ref the title property of the API Gateway it is better.

Pasted below are parts of the Cloudformation Template which defines the API Gateway and Dashboard.

Cloudformation Template for API Gateway:

```
EmployeeApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: "2.0"
        info:
          description: "This API allows clients to query and manage employees"
          version: "1.0.0"
          title: "Employee Management API"
          contact:
            email: "me@me.com"
        basePath: "/v1"
        tags:
        - name: "employee"
          description: "Operations related to a employee"
        schemes:
        - "https"
        paths:
          /brands:
.
.
.
```

Cloudformation Template for Dashboard for API Gateway

```
EmployeeAPIDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
      DashboardName: "EmployeeAPIDashboard"
      DashboardBody:
        Fn::Sub: '{
              "widgets": [
                  {
                     "type": "metric",
                     "x": 0,
                     "y": 0,
                     "width": 6,
                     "height": 6,
                     "properties": {
                         "view": "timeSeries",
                         "stacked": false,
                         "metrics": [
                             [ "AWS/ApiGateway", "IntegrationLatency", "ApiName", "Employee Management API", "Stage", "Prod", { "period": 86400, "yAxis": "right", "stat": "Sum" } ],
                             [ ".", "Count", ".", ".", ".", ".", { "period": 86400, "stat": "Sum"} ],
                             [ ".", "Latency", ".", ".", ".", ".", { "period": 86400, "yAxis": "right", "stat": "Sum"} ],
                             [ ".", "5XXError", ".", ".", ".", ".", { "period": 86400, "stat": "Sum", "color": "#FF0000" } ],
                             [ ".", "4XXError", ".", ".", ".", ".", { "period": 86400, "stat": "Sum", "color": "#FFA500" } ]
                         ],
                         "region": "us-west-2",
                         "period": 300,
                         "title": "API Gateway"
                     }
                  }
              ]
          }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of October 2018 this is not supported. [Return values for AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#aws-resource-apigateway-restapi-returnvalues) do not include ApiName. Also the [Cloudwatch metrics for ApiGateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/api-gateway-metrics-dimensions.html) only support filtering on ApiName. The workaround we are using is to reference the same stack parameter in both places. So in your case you could do something like

```
Parameters:
  MyApiName:
    Type: String
    Default: "Employee Management API"
Resources:
  EmployeeApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
      Properties:
        DefinitionBody:
          info:
            title: !Ref MyApiName

  EmployeeAPIDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
      Properties:
        DashboardBody:
          Fn::Sub: '{
            "widgets": [
              {
                 "properties": {
                     "metrics": [
                         [ "ApiName", ${MyApiName} ]
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can reference a Stack `Output` across multiple stacks like so:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html

Comment: this doesn't seem relevant